# How to add month to an export macro name?

Tags: excel, vba, export, filenames

i have an macro that exports worksheets to pdf's to a designated folder using their sheet name. What I would like is to add the month in as part of the filename. I can retrieve this from a cell in my workbook. Where in my code would I add this reference to?

```
Dim outFldr As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Variant, sheets_to_select As Variant

outFldr = ActiveWorkbook.Path
sheets_to_select = Array("Summary", "PLC", "MI", "Venture", "EIS", "VCT", "PE", "Debt")

For Each i In sheets_to_select
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=outFldr & "\" & i & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i
MsgBox ("All pdf's exported.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the date from Excel, use for example `format` to get the month number or name and add that to the file name. I prefer to use intermediate variables as this makes the code much easier to read and debug.

Adapt the `format` to create the pattern you want - you could also include the year.

```
For Each i In sheets_to_select
    Dim filename As String, filedate As Date, month As String
    filedate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")       ' Change this so that it reads your cell with the date
    
    month = Format(filedate, "mm") ' For month as 2-digits
    month = Format(filedate, "mmm") ' For month as 3 letters month name
    month = Format(filedate, "mmmm") ' For month as full month name
    
    filename = outFldr & "\" & i & "_" & month & "_.pdf"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
Next i
```

Comment: thanks FunThomas, that works! Although when I try to point the sheet to anything other than 1 I get an error...

Comment: What do you mean with "point the sheet to anything other than 1"?

Comment: Sheets(1) seems to point to my first sheet. The date I want referring to is several sheets across (say on sheet 5). Every time I change the (1) to a (5) it doesn't like it.

Comment: You can access a sheet by its number (`Sheets(1) `) or by name (`Sheets(Summary)`), and of course this can be done using a variable. In your case you are using `i` as variable (not a good name, btw) to loop over a set of sheets, so if the date is within the sheet you want to export, use simply `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1")`.

Comment: ah gotcha, yeah I figured it out. Thanks for your help though in the original edit, much appreciated. Wish you a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!